# django-admin runserver gives error django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, exception, django-admin, environment-variables

I am beginner in Python Django. My Django project were running correctly. But I do not know when I run command

```
django-admin runserver
```

I am getting below error Please help me what went wrong suddenly.? It happens in all Django Projects. How to solve this?

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Just run it by `python manage.py runserver` in the root of your Django project where manage.py is situated. Always try to use virtual environment for your Django projects.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my day. I guess , i am using wrong command. BTW what exactly django-admin runserver does?